# How to change the font for selected words in LaTeX document

Tags: fonts

I am writing a document in LaTeX and I want to change the font of selected words within a paragraph. An example of what I am trying to achieve is this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch to a fixed-width font, you can load any fixed-width font package (such as `tgcursor` or `inconsolata`) and use `\texttt`.  You will rarely if ever want to use more than one fixed-width font in the same document.

If you do need to use a specific font that isn’t one of the predefined font families, you either declare the command with `\newfontfamily` in the modern toolchain with `fontspec`, or `\fontfamily` in legacy NFSS.

I would recommend that you use `\DeclareTextFontCommand` to define the command you will be using inside the body of your document.  This both takes care of some of the fiddly little details, such as italic correction, and also lets you change how you load the font without changing the body in dozens of places.  For example,

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\tgcursor{TeX Gyre Cursor}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textcourier{\tgcursor}
```

could be replaced with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textcourier{\fontfamily{qcr}}
```

to compile with the legacy toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can set the fontfamily using `\fontfamily{<family>}\selectfont`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{ulem}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}

\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
    \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
    \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
    Text in \myuline{Palatino} any new user defined function or 
    \myuline{modification} \par  %switch font after this
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont function \myuline{Text in Times with 
    underline for descendants gly}}\par %switch font after this
    \texttt {function} \par %switch font back to palatino
    \myuline{Text in Palatino with underline for descendants gly}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, you are looking for `\underline{}` and `\texttt{}` basic commands. Generally, to change the style or font size you are looking for the section 6.2 of [The Not So Short
Introduction to LATEX 2ε](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).

The above is to always use the same default roman, sans serif, typewriter and math fonts with standard sizes and it's the only thing the normal user should know (since a page with "enriched text", i.e., with  with more than three or four typefaces, is basically garbage).

Nonetheless, if you need also switch to another fonts (e.g., said change from Computer Modern to Fraktur) the method depend on of the font. Some font packages provide  commands to switch to a particular font family (as `\frakfamily` using the  `yfonts` package). The [LaTeX font Cataloque](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) is the right place to know about many of them.

However, you can see there that most fonts packages are designed only to change the default fonts in the whole document. If you want to use them for only for some  word, I warn you, you will go to the dark side of TeX\LaTeX,  with obscure incantations like the `\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont` suggested by [js bibra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/197451/js-bibra) or more ominous spells as  `\font\Aparecium=pagko \Aparecium` and `\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{sl}`, or even true black magic charms as `\input Acorn.fd \usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}`

The routine example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % scalable cm
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{tgothic}
\begin{document}
foo  \underline{foo} \texttt{foo} \textbf{foo} \emph{foo}\par

{\fontsize{30}{50}\selectfont foo \Huge foo  \normalsize foo \footnotesize foo \tiny foo \fontsize{3}{5}\selectfont foo}\par

{\calligra foo} {\frakfamily foo} {\tgothfamily foo} 

\font\foo=pagko \foo  foo
\font\omding=omding \omding  foo 
\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{sl} foo 
\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n} foo 
\input Acorn.fd \usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n} foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: incantation dark spells magic charms haahaha truly nice write up for a dreary subject