# Switching up two font types (Lato and Raleway) in one body of text

Tags: font-encodings

I would like to switch up between the two font types: Lato and Raleway in one body of text. I spent some time to search for answer but no success. If I set one as default cannot change the selected words to the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[default]{raleway} Set raleway as default
% \usepackage[default]{lato} Set lato as default
\begin{document}
        {\fontfamily{raleway}\selectfont \lipsum[1]}

        {\fontfamily{lato}\selectfont \lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

These are the answers I looked up but could not apply:

[How to change the font for selected words in LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542694/how-to-change-the-font-for-selected-words-in-latex-document)

[How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/25251#25251)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `raleway` without any options will make it the default sans serif font anyway, so you can use `{\sffamily ...}` or `\textsf{...}`.

For `lato`, you can select `\latofamily` manually:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{raleway}
\usepackage{lato}
\begin{document}

{\sffamily This is Raleway. \lipsum[1]}

{\fontfamily{\latofamily}\selectfont This is Lato. \lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are constrained to legacy fonts, it is much easier and more flexible  to use the modern toolchain with `fontspec` package and system fonts, and compiling with xelatex or lualatex. You can define as many (or as few) font switches as you need. OpenType font features become available also.

[image: switching fonts]

(Fonts coloured to highlight the switching.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\fraleway}{Raleway}[Colour=blue]
\newfontfamily{\flato}{Lato}[Colour=red]
\newcommand\parnum{5}
\begin{document}

\sffamily 
This is default sans. 
\lipsum[\parnum]

\fraleway
 This is Raleway. 
 \lipsum[\parnum]
 

\flato
 This is Lato. 
 \lipsum[\parnum]
 

\normalfont\sffamily 
 This is back to default font. 
 \lipsum[\parnum] 
\end{document}
```

To set a font as the sans font for a document, the `\setsansfont{...}` command is used.

Here, Raleway is made the default sans:

[image: default Raleway]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Raleway}
\newfontfamily{\fraleway}{Raleway}[Colour=blue]
\newfontfamily{\flato}{Lato}[Colour=red]
\newcommand\parnum{5}
\begin{document}

\sffamily 
This is default sans. (Raleway) %{\tiny\fontname\font\ }
\lipsum[\parnum]

\fraleway
 This is Raleway. %{\tiny\fontname\font\ }
 \lipsum[\parnum]
 

\flato
 This is Lato. %{\tiny\fontname\font\ }
 \lipsum[\parnum]
 

\normalfont\sffamily 
 This is back to default font. %{\tiny\fontname\font\ }
 \lipsum[\parnum] 
\end{document}
```