# How to use Arial for selected words

Tags: fonts

I need to use bold Arial for selected words, as shown in the paragraph below.

[image]

I am using `pdfLaTeX` in Overleaf.

The answered questions I find give solutions to use Arial for the entire document ([How to set font to Arial throughout the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957/how-to-set-font-to-arial-throughout-the-entire-document)) or [How to change the font for selected words in LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542694/how-to-change-the-font-for-selected-words-in-latex-document), which I can't quite follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you just need bold sans-serif text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text \textbf{\sffamily text} text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you actually need real Arial, I suggest to switch to lualatex or xelatex (you can change the engine in the sidebar of your overleaf project):

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\boldarial}{Arial Bold}

\begin{document}

text {\boldarial text} text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `pdflatex` you can use `uarial` (but this needs to run [`getnonfreefonts`](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{uarial}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\ba}{\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}

Some words in the default font and \ba{arial} for emphasis.

\ba{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\ba{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Chances are the nobody would notice if you use Helvetica instead of Arial. This requires installing nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{helvet}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\ba}{\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}

Some words in the default font and \ba{arial} for emphasis.

\ba{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\ba{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the first option of samcarter_is_at_ansers.xyz we can as well define a new command and avoid lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ba}[1]{\textbf{\sffamily #1}}

\begin{document}
    
    text \ba{text} text.\\
    
    Testo di controllo per vedere se funziona il \ba{nuovo} comando.
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]